# How to stop media player if other video/audio starts playing in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-audiomanager

I have created an android application to play text to speech file using media player but if other audio/video starts playing then also my audio plays i.e two audios are played simultaneously.

Is there any way to stop first audio before starting another audio/video.

Is there any broadcast receiver which will get called on the start of other audio.

I have used -

`mediaPlayer.play()` to play audio.

and `mediaPlayer.pause()` to pause audio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Single instance for mediaPlayer for your application .

Comment: @ADM i'm using single instance only but if we start video then also the my audio plays

Comment: Use [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) with mode.

Comment: @ADM I have used media player for playing audio.

Answer (score 2):

You should use AudioManager service to receive notification whether you receive/lost audio focus ([Managing audio focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html)). Use the following code where you are controlling your media playback like (activity or service)-

```
// Add this code in a method

AudioManager am = null;

// Request focus for music stream and pass AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener
// implementation reference
int result = am.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
{
    // Play
}

// Implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) 
{
    if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT)
    {
        // Pause
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
    {
        // Resume
    }
    else if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS)
    {
        // Stop or pause depending on your need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media player is responsible for playing . AudioManager will provides access    to volume and ringer mode control. Try following code to  stop previous and play next:

```
if (mediaplayer != null)
        if (mediaplayer.isplaying()) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            // start your new audio
        } else {
            // start your new audio
        }
```